# Counting right and wrong answers

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT - I have now got a working counter for the right answer and done exactly the same for wrong answers but cannot get it working. It will not count more than one - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/33/

I am creating a spelling game for children where empty spaces are highlighted in a grid and clues are given to spell the word correctly by clicking the corresponding letters on the side of the grid.

If you get the word right the space in the grid fades away with the use of "wordglow2". If you get it wrong it glows red with "wordglow4".

In my spelling game I want to count the number of right and wrong attempts of the words, and then show them at the end.

I have created a div in the HTML called "counter" Which should display the correct answers, but after 1 correct answer it doesn't keep count.

Here is the script

```
var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var threeLetter = (completeLetters / 3);
var rightWords = $(threeLetter).length;
    $('.counter').text(rightWords).show();

        if (threeLetter == 3) {
            $('table').fadeOut(2000);

            }
```

I have tried to create a variable called "rightWord" that takes the length of the "threeLetter" and then displays it through the counter. It counts up to 1 then stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var threeLetter = (completeLetters / 3);
```

`threeLetter` is number

```
var rightWords = $(threeLetter).length;
```

here you trying to select number

This game contain errors and it crash my browser, but count is working in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/29/

Comment: I have just done that part myself, was just about to edit. I have tried the reverse way for incorrect but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz Sorry, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry. Now I have created a count for both right and wrong answers. The only problem I have is that the wrong answers won't count the more than one for each word. Have you any idea why? Here is where I am atm http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/30/ @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz `$('.wordglow4').length` always return 3 elements. As I understand animation remove class `wordglow4`.

Comment: @sMilbz `if ($(right).show())` return jquery object, I think you trying to write: `if ($(right).is(':visible'))`

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say, could you explain again or maybe show me a fiddle @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz You trying to calculate wrong answers by red boxes, but in your game maximum numbers of red boxes equal 3, 3/3 == 1, that's why it never print more than 1. Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/36/

Comment: Thanks webdeveloper that is the perfect answer. There is one thing that I have made since I asked that question and cannot seem to fit it in. It is the ability to choose the amount of words you want to populate the grid with from the list. Can you help? @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz You tacking about this block of code `if (score.right == 3) { $('table').fadeOut(2000); }`?

Comment: No I mean at the top of the code where the grid is generated. I used to be able to state how many words from the list I want to pull through. Now it seems it just pulls all words from the <ul> @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz I don't know how I get 47 version after 36, look at `var wordsData = wordlist.find('li').slice(0, 4);` http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/47/

Comment: Is there any way to make it choose the words from the list at random? @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz Of course you can, but I didn't see any sense in this, you already have logic for randomize, also you have number of words  to win. It's better to set amount in table render block.

Comment: I mean randomise the choices because eventually it will have 100 words in the list, so it will need to have variety otherwise it will pick the first 6 everytime. So you still decide the number of words you pick, but the ones it brings back are picked at random from the list of words @webdeveloper

Comment: @sMilbz quick solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/55/ (`var amount = 3; // <- magic number`)